# Removing special chars from URL

Tags: java, android

I want to remove any of special characters in a url. I tried the StringEscapeUtils class to remove special chars. But no use of that. **For eg: http%3A%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2FNdtvNews-TopStories** .   Any of ideas are welcome

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have used java.net.URLDecoder.decode("String") in the past. Should still hold.

Comment: This method is deprecated. Use the two parameter version which includes the encoding as the second paramter. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
> URLDecoder.decode(param1AfterEncoding, "UTF-8");
```

You can learn more by [This example](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-decode-url-strings.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use this...

```
URLDecoder.decode(urlValue, "UTF-8");
```