# spring boot remove invalid symbol found in url

Tags: java, url

java how to remove url illegal characters such like

receive keyword from html input. it may exist illegal characters

```
?keywords=//..\\
```

or other illegal characters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing special chars from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205853/removing-special-chars-from-url)

Comment: You are right it is dublicate

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit not clear, but validating URL has nothing to do with Spring boot. Look at the classes [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) and [URLDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html). Those are the tools to standardize URL Strings